# how to update Busybox commands by modifying /lib and /bin directly?

Tags: linux, busybox

I am developing on a router from Advantech that has manufacturer's firmware built with BusyBox and LTIB. It's built with bare minimum commands, and I want to extend the commands to meet some needs. Luckily Advantech provides firmware source which contain the BusyBox config file. I used that and compile the BusyBox with additional commands I need. However, the LTIB built firmware a user can compile doesn't include their proprietary software. So I am unable to use the firmware .bin file compiled by LTIB directly because it'll miss some other core functionalities, which I haven't yet confirmed what missing functionalities. So I tried replacing /bin/busybox with the newly compiled one, but it shows segfault when I run it. So I guessed I had to modify /lib/ too, but while trying to modify /lib, I broke the system.  Is there any safe way to modify /lib, /bin directly to update BusyBox commands?

A side note, I think the Linux on this device is just the Linux kernel, below is what is shows:

```
# cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.12.10+ (root@localhost) (gcc version 4.9.4 (GCC) ) #1 custom
```

Comment: You can try to compile BusyBox as a static binary, which may remove any doubt of lib folder. To add extra commands, you've to edit the config file.

Comment: *"but it shows segfault when I run it."*  -- You would be better off analyzing this issue better and/ provide more info instead of guessing that the next step should be replacing **/lib**.  *"So I guessed I had to modify /lib/ too"* -- That's probably a bad idea. FYI the Linux kernel, the toolchain, and userspace programs can be dependent on the libc, so unless you plan on replacing everything (which you already know you cannot), you better try to build with a similar toolchain and the same version of whatever libc that's already installed.

Comment: @Biswapriyo thanks, I tried to set BusyBox CONFIG_STATIC=y, but then there's some missing libraries like lpam, lpam_mist in the GCC crosscompilation toolchain provided. I am guessing adding the library to the toolchain is probably not very easy.

Comment: @sawdust what do you suggest on analyzing segfault?

Comment: Did you try a google search for e.g. "how to analyze linux segfault"?